# Why does function called in Adapter from another activity always return false?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

Inside ExamAcitivy :

passExamState always returns false even though its value changes to true after the setOnClickListener, when called in the adapter I need it to return the state acordingly. How do i propely pass the examState and its value to the adapter?

```
class ExamActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    private var examState  = false

    private val questionData = QuestionData()
    private var  questionAdapter = QuestionAdapter(questionData)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exam)

        questionViewPager.adapter = questionAdapter
  

        endExam.setOnClickListener {
           examState=true
        }
            
    }

    fun passExamState() : Boolean {
        return examState
    }
}
```

Inside My ViewPager2Adapter :

```
class QuestionAdapter(private val questionData: QuestionData) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.QuestionViewPagerViewHolder>() {

inner class QuestionViewPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

   //itemviews

    init {
        if (!ExamActivity().passExamState()) {
            getthis()
        }else{
            getthat()
        }
    }

}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QuestionViewPagerViewHolder {
    return QuestionViewPagerViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_question, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: QuestionViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {

  

    //itemviews

    if (!ExamActivity().passExamState()){
        dothis()
    }else{
        dothat()

    }


}
```

//itemcount
}

Comment: yes and its initialized as false

Comment: Your function is logically equivalent to simply returning `examState`. As for why `examState` is false when you don't expect it to be, we'd have to see how and when you're changing it, and how and when you're checking it.

Comment: Yes it is indeed the same as returning examState itself but I still do not understand why it only returns false when the value has meanwhile changed throughout the code.

Comment: i will update the post

Comment: updated please take a look and thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new ExamActivity instance and using that instance's property to check `passExamState()`. In this line, which appears twice in your code:

```
if (!ExamActivity().passExamState()) {
```

you are calling the `ExamActivity` constructor to construct a new Activity, so you are not checking the state of the actual Activity that is on the screen.

The proper, encapsulated way to do this is to create the appropriate Boolean property in your Adapter, and allow your Activity to modify that property. This way of organizing the code reduces inter-dependence. The Adapter doesn't have to know about the existence of the Activity. For example:

```
//In ExamActivity:

endExam.setOnClickListener {
    examState = true // If you even need to track this property in the Activity.
                     // Maybe you can remove the property entirely.

    questionAdapter.examState = true
}

// Adapter class:

class QuestionAdapter(private val questionData: QuestionData) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionAdapter.QuestionViewPagerViewHolder>() {
   
    var examState = false

    inner class QuestionViewPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : 
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        init {
            if (!examState) { // and the same in onBindViewHolder
                getthis()
            }else{
                getthat()
            }
       }

    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: thank you it worked, after trying so much and the answer beeing so simple. also had to notifyDataSetChanged() in order to make it work.